# how to normalize prediction values in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

A simple feed forward DNN with relevant .csv files can be found here https://github.com/jhsmith12345/tensorflow/blob/normalize_prediction/tf_from_csv.py

This piece of code

```
classification = prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [[9,3]]})
print (classification)
```

is outputting

```
[[ -12.2412138  -17.24327469 ]]
```

I am expecting a prediction that conforms to the labels, which are 1 or 0. Something like

```
[[ 0   1 ]]
```

I believe that my predictive values are not getting normalized by a softmax, but have no idea how to proceed. Any help is appreciated! Also, I'm more than happy to post the full code here but didn't want to clutter the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clear, in your code

```
prediction = neural_network_model(x)
prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [[9,3]]})
# output is [[ -12.2412138  -17.24327469 ]]
```

and you confuse why the range is not 0 ~ 1, right ?
because softmax doesn't apply on prediction
you use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`
For I know, this function apply softmax to `prediction` before compute cross entropy
But it doesn't change the value of `prediction`

I think you can
do softmax then compute cross entropy, finally print `prediction` directly (it means can't use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`)

or, change nothing, but do softmax before print `prediction`

Comment: Thanks, I tried """classification = tf.nn.softmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [[9,3]]}))"""  with produced """Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)""" I don't think this is what I'm looking for, but not sure.

Comment: I think it will be `result = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)` then `print result.eval(feed_dict={x: [[9,3]]})`